# Can I use Devise controller helper methods in a Grape API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-grape

I have a [grape](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape)-based API whose only clients are browser-based users who are already authenticated to my app through Devise. I was hoping to be able to take advantage of some of the devise controller helper methods like `current_user`, and also to return a 403 if there is no current authenticated user.  Is there a reasonable way to do this?

I naively tried just importing the controller helper methods:

```
class API < Grape::API
  prefix 'api'
  format :json

  include Devise::Controllers::Helpers

  get 'hello' do
    # would like to be able to use current_user here
    { result: 'hello' }
  end
end
```

`current_user` and the other helper methods remain unavailable and throw `undefined local variable or method 'current_user'`.

Is there a way to take advantage of the authentication that devise has already done here and use that within my grape api methods?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this gem? 
grape_devise - https://github.com/justinm/grape_devise

I had similar requirement of using devise helper methods, But i was using devise_token_auth instead of devise for api authentication. Used this Gem https://github.com/mcordell/grape_devise_token_auth for devise helpers in grape endpoints.

Please share answers if you have already found the solution.